# Подскажите, как в QT проверить, есть ли у приложения разрешение isExternalStorageManager() (Android)

Tags: android, qt

Вызываю из QT интент и даю приложению разрешение MANAGE ALL FILES. Как программно узнать, что оно уже дано?
Знаю, что надо вызвать нативную функцию Андроид "Environment.isExternalStorageManager()", но не понимаю, как.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
jboolean value = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticMethod<jboolean>("android/os/Environment", "isExternalStorageManager");
```

Comment: Сердечно благодарю. Не подскажете, где почитать про такое? Чтобы перестать быть обезьяной с гранатой...

Comment: Где почитать не знаю, поищите материалы по JNI для понимания как связывается Java-код и нативный и как вызывается одно из другого и наоборот. В Qt всё так же, просто добавлены классы обёртки для удобства и сокращения кода, легко находятся в [документации](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/classes.html).